# Jquery & Javascript - how to remove strings from the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, qr-code

I want to remove strings from this page . I have a QR Code Scanner, I tried to look on how to remove this string but it is not being removed. now is there any possibility on removing this certain word by using its input?

here is what the page looks like the highlight text is the one that i would like to remove

[image]

here is my input

```
<p id="scanned-QR"></p>
```

but i dont know the possiblity if it can be done with jquery or javascript, is there any.

here is what i knew the problem is `scannedQR[txt] = res.format + ": " + res.code;` i tried to removed `res.format + ": " +` but still the word persists

**Expected Output** - I just want to remove the `Code128` from the page

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187722/discussion-on-question-by-summer-winter-jquery-javascript-how-to-remove-stri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]
you can change only this "scannedQR[txt] = +  + res.code;"

```
scannedQR[txt] = + res.code;
```

Comment: it cant be because there's a specific barcode that is already finished so i cant do this sir sorry

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: okay what is the name page of the page? `main.js` or `index.html` or what js file?

Comment: I already tried it sir :( cna you please send me your zip file? thanks

Comment: it is not really working i still see the `Code128:` even when I delete all the codes in `main.js` the project is still working why is that? what browser are you testing?

Comment: and our project is not the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187700/discussion-between-mohammad-malek-and-summer-winter).